# VSTO Application Installation via MSI - Best way forward?

Tags: installation, vsto, exe, outlook-addin

I have developed an Outlook Add In and I need to install it across all staff PCs company wide. I have managed to create an MSI installer package, but it only seems to place the neccessary files onto the target PC, and then the setup.exe has to be selected anyway.

I have been informed that setup.exe ( or click Once ) cannot be used for a silent install across all computers.

What is the best way forward for achieving a company wide installation?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an MSI installer and then use it to deploy the software using GPO. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for creating MSI installers and [How to use Group Policy to remotely install software in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816102) for using GPO.

Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [Deploy Office 2013 by using Group Policy computer startup scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [HowTo: Install a COM add-in automatically using Windows Server Group Policy](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/01/25/automatic-installation-windows-group-policy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deploy the add-in via a startup script or other software deployment mechanism.  You can install silently as well.  See:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775850(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet framework, VCRedist, VSTO runtime and your MSI, all can be installed silently. Just google for each of them and prepare batch script for them.

Setup.exe is nothing but a batch starter with some checks for installations.